# Parsing json synchronously from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, synchronous

I'm trying to get title of a youtube video. So i'm using jQuery to parse json. But it works asynchronously, so the answer comes after the page loaded. The result is:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym0hZG-zNOk (undefined)

How can i fix it?

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/3vQht/

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym0hZG-zNOk";

        var videoID = link.substring(link.indexOf("=") + 1, link.length);

        document.writeln("<a target='_blank' href='" + link + "'>" + link.bold() + "</a> (" + name(videoID) + ")<br>");

        function name(value) {
            var source = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + value + "?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc&callback=?";
            var fin;

            $.getJSON(source, function(json) {
                fin = json.data.title;
                console.log(fin);
            });

            return fin;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you must have it synchronous? Simply modifying the DOM once the information available would be more robust and won't block the browser during data fetching.

Comment: i want to have it synchronously because the text in brackets after link is "undefined". It tells the data can't come before the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy,
 here is the solution :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function name(value) {
        var source = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + value + "?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: source,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                alert("here is the title: "+json.data.title+" .Use it how you want!");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym0hZG-zNOk";
        var videoID = link.substring(link.indexOf("=") + 1, link.length);
        name(videoID);
    });
</script>
```

If you want to get your data sync just use this version:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: source,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                alert("here is the title: "+json.data.title+" .Use it how you want!");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON` is asynchronous, so when the `return fin;` is reached, the data hasn't been fetched yet.

Everything that depends on the JSON ***MUST*** be inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefere, you can also fetch your data synchronously. Check the [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `async` parameter.

EDIT: Just figured that you're loading your data using JSONP and that it's not possible to do that synchronously. You need to use asynchronous callbacks instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with their api, but a quick look at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

indicates that they support jsonp callbacks so that you can prepend a script that does sends the data to a callback function (just add &callback=yourFunction to the end of the url)

```
function prependScriptFromUrl(s){
  var a=document.createElement("script");
  var b=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  a.src=s;
  b.insertBefore(a,b.firstChild)
}
```